# Karma watch on specific file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a `karma.conf.js` like this:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({

    files : [
        'static_dev/js/lib/underscore-min.js',
        'static_dev/js/lib/angular.1.2.9.min.js',
        'static_dev/js/lib/angular-cookies.1.1.5.min.js',
        'static_dev/js/lib/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.10.0.js',
        'static_dev/js/lib/angular-tags-0.2.10-tpls.min.js',
        'static_dev/js/lib/angular-mocks.js',

        'static_dev/js/angular/modules/*.js',
        'static_dev/js/angular/controllers/**/*.js',
        'static_dev/js/angular/directives/**/*.js',
        'static_dev/js/angular/services/**/*.js',

        'static_dev/js/angular/**/test/*.js'
    ],

    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    autoWatch: true,

    colors: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

})}
```

And it all works fine, however I would like to "autoWatch" only the files that match `'static_dev/js/angular/**/test/*.js'` , is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the complete pattern syntax for your files, this way you can disable watching on files you don't want to:

```
files : [
  //this pattern will NOT be watched
  {pattern: 'path/to/**/*.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true},

  //this one will be watched
  {pattern: 'path/to/other/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true}
],

 autowatch: true
```

Please note that `watched`, `included` and `served` default values are **`true`**.

> "If `autoWatch` is `true` all files that have set `watched` to `true` will be watched for changes."

From : [Karma configuration - Files](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/files.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
files : [
    ...
    {
        pattern: 'static_dev/js/angular/**/test/*.js',
        watched: true
    }
]
```

try this one

Comment: `watched: true` is the default value, to disable autowatch on files/pattern it must be set to `false` for these ones.